# JavaScript, track window screen width

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that tells what the current width of the user's screen is
but when i resize window to width less than 1024 that function doesnt output width less than 1024

```
  function xxx(){
    var x = window.screen.Width
    console.log(x)
    }
    setInterval(xxx, 1000)
```

output:

```
1024
```

even if screen width less than 1024
how can i fix this without using @media requests?

already tried:

`window.screen.innerwidth`

Comment: it was so hard to paste the exact actual code you used? there are so many mistakes in just 5 lines

Comment: screen width !== window width. The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window) cover basically every different approach to retrieving screen/window sizes.

Answer (score 4):

Like [@YoussoufOumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15288641/yousoumar) said instead of using `setInterval` to get the user's screen width, use `resize` event to get the screen width whenever the screen resolution changes.

> `window.screen.width` get only the user's screen width and it doesn't change according to the manual resizing of the browser

Instead `window.innerWidth` gets the browser width and it changes according to the manual resizing of the browser

```js
function widthResizer(){
  var width = window.innerWidth
  console.log(width)
}

// Getting the width of the browser on load
widthResizer()

// Getting the width of the browser whenever the screen resolution changes.
window.addEventListener('resize', widthResizer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting up a `setIntervall` to track screen width changes, use the built in `resize` event.

> As @Kumara pointed it, you would wanna use `window.innerWidth`, instead of `window.screen.width`, as the last one give the screen's original size, not the resized one.

```js
function xxx(){
  var x = window.innerWidth
  console.log(x)
}

// that gives you the width on load
xxx(); 

// that is for when you change the width manually
window.addEventListener('resize', xxx);
```